# IEnumerable.ToArray<T>() vs. IEnumerable.Cast<T>().ToArray()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When trying to obtain an array of objects from an IEnumerable collection of objects (cast differently than the array I want), I know I can first cast the source collection to the proper type, and then obtain an array from that, but the method **`ToArray<T>()`** gives me the impression that it can handle both of those operations in one step.   From my experience, though, I have *never* been able to find a case where the **`ToArray<T>()`** method works for any T except the original source's T (which, in my mind, makes **`ToArray<T>()`** silly, since it does the same thing that the non-generic **ToArray()** already does).

So my question is, am I missing the point of the **`ToArray<T>()`** method, and I'm trying to make it do something it was never intended for, or is there something silly I'm missing with regard to the method, and what I'm trying to do does generally follow its intent?

Here is a concrete example to illustrate my issue:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class Foo : IFoo { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Suppose a list of Foos was created
    List<Foo> src = new List<Foo>();

    // I would be safe obtaining an array of IFoos from that list, but

    // This is not supported (although intellisense shows the method is there, the compiler balks):
    // IFoo[] results = src.ToArray<IFoo>();

    // Whereas this works just fine:
    IFoo[] results = src.Cast<IFoo>().ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason `ToArray<T>()` is generic is so that it can operate on *any* `IEnumerable<T>`, not so that you can supply a different `T`:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self) { ... }
```

You should never need to provide the `T` yourself.  If you did, as in your example, the method would expect to receive, for example, an `IEnumerable<IFoo>`, which you are not supplying.

FYI, there is no "non-generic ToArray()".  The compiler is inferring the `T` generic argument based on the type of enumerable you call ToArray() on.

Comment: That makes sense. it looks like I was confusing the ToArray() vs. ToArray<T>(). 

I had assumed those were two different methods, but it looks like ToArray() actually just redirects to an implicit interpretation of ToArray<T>() based on the T of the source IEnumerable. Maybe it's personal biases, but I still feel like that seems a bit awkward. Maybe that's just the nature of generics.  I would think there would be a way to "hide" the generic T, but I can't really think of a good way to do that since (as you mentioned) IEnumerable needs a T.

Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem.  Yes, you are right -- they are the same method.  If you call a generic method and don't supply any type arguments, the compiler will try to infer them for you.  It sounds awkward, but it can save a LOT of typing.  Imagine if you had a List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>> -- .ToArray() is much nicer than .ToArray<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>(). (As a side note, the compiler will prefer a non-generic method, if one exists and your arguments are compatible with its signature, otherwise it will look for a usable generic overload.)

Comment: Is is possible to use a different `T` in C#4 because the `T` in `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant?